# PowerShell Script to display all users part of AD security groups within an OU in AD

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory

I am new to PowerShell I am trying to display all AD security groups within a certain OU and to display each user part of that security group.

I want to show username and name and the security group name to a CSV file.

I have managed to get this information but I had to manually add the AD security group name within the script itself:

```
$groups = "GroupName1", "GroupName2", "GroupName3", "GroupName4", "GroupName5"

$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | select samaccountname, name, @{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}}
}

$results

$results | Export-csv C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The above script outputs the information I require but as stated above I have to manually enter the Security GroupName within the script itself.

I think the command I need to use is **Get-ADGroup**

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase 'OUdnHere'` to search for all groups under your desired Organizational Unit, then you can simply apply the same logic you already have:

1. Loop over the Groups
2. Get their memberships
3. Construct the output
4. Export to CSV

```
$ou = 'distinguished name of my OU here'
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($member in Get-ADGroupMember $_) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $member.SamAccountName
            Name           = $member.Name
            GroupName      = $_.Name
            Description    = $_.Description
        }
    }
} | Export-csv C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Dude you are made this sooooo much easy thanks for your help!!!!!

Comment: @S.Mahmood happy to help! please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (add the correct dn for the OU of course):

```
$Groups = Get-AdGroup -SearchBase "ou=OuName,DC=contoso,DC=local" -Filter * | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Or somewhat shorter and easier to read according to me:

```
$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -SearchBase "ou=OuName,DC=contoso,DC=local" -Filter *).Name
```

Untested code, but you get the gist of it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help I tried both commands with the correct CN for my OU and got filters request so I added this to end of my DN OU for both commands -filter  {GroupCategory -eq "Security"} nothing it getting outputted. Sorry I am not the best with PowerShell probably doing something really wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah the filter thing, of course... Just add -Filter * to the command (I'll edit my post with this). You don't get any output but maybe that's because it's being written to $Groups variable? Just type $Groups followed by return and you should get the groups.

Comment: Thanks for that your right I had to type in $Groups after that command which outputted the group part of that OU I defined. Another question how would I would put $Groups to a CSV file

Comment: Just the list of groups? $Groups | Export-csv <path> -NoTypeInformation